# image scaling CGDataProviderCopyData

Tags: ios, xcode, image-processing

**update 1**

[I have found a promising apple doc here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1509/_index.html)describing CGDataProviderCopyData. I think this does what I originally asked about by taking a drawing from a context and extracting the pixel values.

The example code uses `CGImageGetDataProvider` and some other features that I do not understand so that I cannot figure out how to implement their functions. How do I take information from the variable `con` or from its context and get access to the pixels?

**update 1**

**update 0**

Maybe I am asking the wrong question here. `CGContextDrawImage` scales the image from 104 by 104 to 13 by 13 in my case, but then `CGContextDrawImage` displays the image. Maybe I need to find the part of `CGContextDrawImage` which just does the scaling.

I have found `initWithData:scale:` in the "UIImage Class Reference". But I don't know how to supply the data for that method. The scale I want is 0.25 .

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data scale:(CGFloat)scale
```

Can someone tell me how to supply the `(NSData *)data` for my app?

**update 0**

```
//
//  BSViewController.m

#import "BSViewController.h"

@interface BSViewController ()
@end

@implementation BSViewController


- (IBAction) chooseImage:(id) sender{


    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
    UIImage* testCard = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad 7D.JPG"];
    CGSize sz = [testCard size];
    CGImageRef num = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([testCard CGImage],CGRectMake(532, 0, 104, 104));
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake( 250,650));
    CGContextRef con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextDrawImage(con, CGRectMake(0, 0, 13, 13) ,num);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.workingImage = CFBridgingRelease(num);
    CGImageRelease(num);
```

I am working on the transition from above to below.

More specifically I need to feed imageRef the correct input. I want to give the imageRef a 13 by 13 image, but when I give imageRef `num` it gets a 104 by 104 image, and when I give imageRef `con` it gets a 0 by 0 image. (Another tentative approach is mentioned at the bottom.)

[The code below is Brandon Trebitowski's](http://brandontreb.com/image-manipulation-retrieving-and-updating-pixel-values-for-a-uiimage/)

```
    CGImageRef imageRef = num;
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    NSLog(@"the width: %u", width);
    NSLog(@"the height: %u", height);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    NSLog(@"Stop 3");

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
    int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * 0) + 0 * bytesPerPixel;
    for (int ii = 0 ; ii < width * height ; ++ii)
    {
        int outputColor = (rawData[byteIndex] + rawData[byteIndex+1] + rawData[byteIndex+2]) / 3;

        rawData[byteIndex] = (char) (outputColor);
        rawData[byteIndex+1] =  (char) (outputColor);
        rawData[byteIndex+2] = (char) (outputColor);

        byteIndex += 4;
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I have also experimented with defining `self.workingImage` one of the following two ways and supplying that to `imageRef`.

```
self.workingImage = num;
self.workingImage = (__bridge UIImage *)(num);
CGImageRef imageRef = [self.workingImage CGImage];
```

Comment: Can I ask stupid question? What's the final result of these image's scaling? Do you want just scale the image? If it's true may be will be good idea just change `UIImageView`'s frame property to 13x13 and it will scale image for you automatically? Sorry if I have not got your idea, could you describe it pls.

Comment: No, I need the actual data and do not even want to show the result. You can see from the code that I need "rawData" so that I can attempt to recognize it.

Comment: I have just stumbled on `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. What is that? "Creates a bitmap-based graphics context with the specified options." And the options include scale.

Comment: Please look at my edited question which asks how to implement `CGDataProviderCopyData` on my code.

Answer (score 0):

I changed 2 lines and added 3 lines and got the results I wanted.
The main change was to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` so that the rescaling could be done before the image was drawn.

```
@implementation BSViewController


- (IBAction) chooseImage:(id) sender{


    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
    UIImage* testCard = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad 7D.JPG"];
    CGSize sz = [testCard size];
    CGImageRef num = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([testCard CGImage],CGRectMake(532, 0, 104, 104));
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake( 104,104), NO, 0.125);  // Changed
    CGContextRef con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextDrawImage(con, CGRectMake(0, 0, 104, 104) ,num);  // Changed
    UIImage* im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  // Added
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.workingImage = CFBridgingRelease(num);
    CGImageRelease(num);


    UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:im];   // Added
    [self.imageView addSubview: iv];  // Added
    CGImageRef imageRef = [im CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
```

etc.